# call asmx web service from android

Tags: java, c#, android

I have this C# working example

```
void Main()
{
      string r = String.Format("<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><TrackMobileApp xmlns=\" url \" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><device>test device</device><imei>000000</imei><ipAddress>192.168.1.1</ipAddress><timeStamp>{0}</timeStamp></TrackMobileApp></s:Body></s:Envelope>", DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));

      HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("asmx url");
      wr.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
      wr.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"soap action url\"");
      wr.Method = "POST";
      wr.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
      using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wr.GetRequestStream()))
      {
            sw.Write(r);
      }

      HttpWebResponse rs = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
      if (rs.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                  xd.LoadXml(sr.ReadToEnd());
                  xd.InnerXml.Dump();
            }
      }
}
```

I've tried this in android:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 private String downloadContent(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        int length = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "soap action url");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = convertInputStreamToString(is, length);
            return contentAsString;
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

and I'm calling it using:

new DownloadTask().execute("asmx url");

how can I attach body to that `HttpURLConnection`  ?

or if there's something more to do tell me.. I'm beginner at java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(body != null) {
                DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                byte[] data = body.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                writer.write(data);

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
```

Comment: Put it before conn.connect().
body is the body you need to send with the request. What is your body format? Is it Json?

Comment: nope it's xml. check `string r = String.Format...` that's what I want to send